# Holomorphic function has a zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D\subset\mathbb C$ a domain and $f:D\to \mathbb C$ holomorphic. Show that if $|f|$ has a local minimum in $a\in D$, then $f(a)=0$.

Proof. (probably some errors, I'm sure the proof is short and simple but I can't come up with something better unfortunately)

If $f(a)\neq 0$, then $|f(a)|>0$. So $|f(a)|$ has a nbhd $N_\epsilon$ without $0$ and $|f(z)|$ has no zeros on $N_\epsilon$, thus $1/|f|$ is holomorphic on $N_\epsilon$ and takes its maximum on $\partial N_\epsilon\subset D$. This maximum is a new minimum for $|f|$ smaller than $|f(a)|$ which would be a contradiction if this proof didn't contain errors (I'd guess $\partial N_\epsilon\subsetneq D$ is one).

Comment: I think the proof is fine.

Comment: A small mistake: $1/\lvert f\rvert$ is not holomorphic; $1/f$ is.

Comment: What if $a\in \partial D$ ? What is $G$ ?

Comment: G is supposed to be D. So $a\notin\partial D$. I edited it.

Comment: What about $f \equiv 3$? You should add non-constantness to the hypotheses.

Comment: I am confused on your definition of $N_{\epsilon}$. If I understand correctly, it is a neighborhood around $\vert f(a) \vert,$ why should it be in the image of $\vert f(z) \vert$. You could prove it using the open mapping theorem on $f$, but I think this exercise is about the Maximum Modulus Principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments above, we will assume $f$ is not a constant function.

Suppose $\vert f(a) \vert \neq 0$ is a minimum for $\vert f(z) \vert$ in $D$. Since $ \vert f(a) \vert$ is a minimum and is non zero, it implies that $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is well-defined and holomorphic in $D$. Moreover, $\vert f(a) \vert$ was a minimum, it implies that $\frac{1}{\vert f(a) \vert} \geq \frac{1}{\vert f(z) \vert}$ for all $z \in D$. Now using the Maximum Modulus Principle, we see that $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is constant, and hence $f(z)$ is constant, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Small note, you mean $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is constant, not $\frac{1}{z}$ is constant.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. I fixed it.

Comment: Np, just a mathgrammarnazi

Comment: The idea is the same but your proof looks sharper. Thanks!